# search and print the value inside tags using script

Tags: sed, awk, hp-ux

I have a file like this. `abc.txt`

```
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>34.908</a><r>23</r><a>234.09</a><p>234</p><a>23</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>hiisadf</hi>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>345</a><po>234</po><a>345</a></ra>
```

What I have to do is I have to find `<ra>` tag  and for inside `<ra>` tag there is `<a>` tag whose valeus I have to store the values inside of  into some variables which I need to process further. How should I do this.?

values inside  tag within  tag are:
`34.908,234.09,23`
`345,345`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
cat file
<ra><r>12.34</r><e>235</e><a>34.908</a><r>23</r><a>234.09</a><p>234</p><a>23</a></ra><a>12344</a><ra><e>45</e><a>666</a></ra>
<hello>sadfaf</hello>
<hi>no print from this line</hi><a>256</a>
<ra><s>asdf</s><qw>345</qw><a>345</a><po>234</po><a>345</a></ra>
```

```
awk -v RS="<" -F">" '/^ra/,/\/ra/ {if (/^a>/) print $2}' file
34.908
234.09
23
666
345
345
```

It take in care if there are multiple `<ra>...</ra>` groups in one line.

---

A small variation:

```
awk -v RS=\< -F\> '/\/ra/ {f=0} f&&/^a/ {print $2} /^ra/ {f=1}' file
34.908
234.09
23
666
345
345
```

---

How does it work:

```
awk -v RS="<" -F">" '   # This sets record separator to < and gives a new line for every <
/^ra/,/\/ra/ {          # within the record starting witn "ra" to record ending with "/ra" do
    if (/^a>/)          # if line starts with an "a" do
    print $2}'          # print filed 2
```

To see how changing RS works try:

```
awk -v RS="<" '$1=$1' file
ra>
r>12.34
/r>
e>235
/e>
a>34.908
/a>
r>23
/r>
a>234.09
/a>
p>234
...
```

---

To store it in an variable you can do as BMW suggested:

```
var=$(awk ...)
var=$(awk -v RS=\< -F\> '/\/ra/ {f=0} f&&/^a/ {print $2} /^ra/ {f=1}' file)
echo $var
34.908 234.09 23 666 345 345
echo "$var"
34.908
234.09
23
666
345
345
```

Since its many values, you can use an array:

```
array=($(awk -v RS=\< -F\> '/\/ra/ {f=0} f&&/^a/ {print $2} /^ra/ {f=1}' file))
echo ${array[2]}
23
echo ${var2[0]}
34.908
echo ${var2[*]}
34.908 234.09 23 666 345 345
```

Comment: No.. I have to search for <ra> tag only <ra> for <a> values I have to use, there are many other tags also which contains <a> but I dont want that value inside <a> tag. and this solution is not giving required output

Comment: Updated to take in care more than one group of `ra` tags on one line.

Comment: Thank you for the updated version, Its working :), and How will I store these values into a variable to process it further.and I will be very thankful if you help me explaining your code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation,And how will I use those variables, One way is to redirect the output into another file and then read those values from the file and use it, is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: @avinashse, assign to a variable, use `var=$(awk ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Use gnu grep's Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions

```
grep -oP "(?<=<ra>).*?(?=</ra>)" file |grep -Po "(?<=<a>).*?(?=</a>)"
```

#### explanation

- the first grep will get the content in `ra` tag. Even there are several ra tags in one line, it still can identified.
- The second grep get the content in `a` tag

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am using HP-UNIX, and P and o are showing illegal options.

Comment: Ok, I updated the tags in your question. If can, install GNU grep, you needn't root permission to do that, you can install it in your home directory with your own account.